# Naturally induced type in flag algebras

Tags: logic, graph-theory

[In Razborov's paper on flag algebras](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~razborov/files/flag.pdf) (in particular, the second paragraph under section 2.2), he writes:

> Given a type $\sigma$ of size $k$, $k' \leq k$ and an injective mapping
>   $\eta : [k'] \rightarrow [k]$, let $\sigma|_{\eta}$ be the naturally induced type of size $k'$
>   (that is, for any predicate symbol $P(x_{1}, ... , x_{r})$ in $L$ and any $i_{1}, ... ,i_{r} \in [k']$, $\sigma|_{\eta} \vDash P(i_{1}, ..., i_{r})$ iff
>   $\sigma \vDash P(\eta(i_{1}), ..., \eta(i_{r}))$. For a $\sigma$-flag $F=(M,\theta)$, the $\sigma|_{\eta}$-flag $F|_{\eta}$ is defined as $F|_{\eta} = (M, \theta\eta)$.

I am unfamiliar with the basic model theory that this paper is written in and am more interested in the application to graph theory. In the context of graph theory, types are essentially graphs with vertices labelled in bijection with some set of integers; in this case, $\sigma$ is a graph on $k$ vertices with those vertices labelled in bijection with $[k]$.

My question is: how should I be thinking about this "induced type" $\sigma|_{\eta}$ in the context of graph theory? I see that it is a *smaller* type of size $k'$, but how are these vertices labelled in relation to the vertices in $\sigma$?

Comment: I hope my answer helps, but unrelatedly, I found [Andrzej Grzesik's PhD thesis](http://ssdnm.mimuw.edu.pl/pliki/prace-studentow/st/pliki/andrzej-grzesik-d.pdf) to be a better reference for learning how to flag algebra.

Comment: Thanks! I remember you from my question on forbidden graphs. I actually have already read through a couple chapters of Grzesik's thesis (and several other papers on flag algebras), but I feel as if none of them really explains "why" things are the way they are, which is why I defer to Razborov's paper. A lot of papers seem to talk about enumerating flags, types, whatever, calculating products, then running CSDP as if it "just works", but this is pretty unsatisfying with regards to understanding.

Comment: I think a good answer to why things are the way they are is that flags are defined to have the *exact* algebraic behavior matching the *approximate* behavior of induced subgraph densities. Grzesik touches on this a little bit in 1.2-1.3, but doesn't spend too much time on it.

Comment: Is this similar to Lemma 2.3 in Razborov's original paper, for the limit of large graphs? Or is this more referring to the idea that flags and densities are somewhat "interchangeable" / the former is representative of the latter?

Comment: Both? Flags are a sort of idealized density *because* flags exactly satisfy the identity that by Lemma 2.3 densities approximately satisfy (and Lemmas 2.1 and 2.2 do this too, though here flags and densities are both exact). We can also say something about how averaging flags is an idealized form of an averaging operation on densities, though I don't see a lemma about this in Razborov's paper.

Comment: You have already been a tremendous help, but I have another question that -- although off this topic -- is "blocking" my understanding and implementation of flag algebras. How exactly does one calculate the product of flags / calculate the "normalizing factor"? I cannot think of a way beyond performing an exhaustive listing that would calculate this, but everyone who has written a flag algebra paper has done it somehow. Would you happen to know?

Comment: There is some amount of exhaustive listing to be done: for example, if you want to multiply "edge" by "non-edge", you would list out all $11$ four-vertex graphs, and in each of them, compute the probability that a random labeling of the vertices as $a,b,c,d$ has an edge $ab$ but no edge $cd$. It's hard to summarize the idea in a comment, but if you want to ask another question about this, I can address it there (especially if you can give specific calculations you want to know how to do).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89015/discussion-between-richard-and-misha-lavrov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The injective mapping $\eta$ tells you the labeling. The type $\sigma|_\eta$ is a subgraph of $\sigma$ (when thinking of both as unlabeled graphs); the vertices labeled $1, 2, \dots, k'$ in $\sigma|_\eta$ are labeled $\eta(1), \eta(2), \dots, \eta(k')$ in $\sigma$.

Let me try to give an example. Let $\sigma$ be the $2$-vertex type with an edge between vertices $1$ and $2$, and let $\sigma'$ be the $1$-vertex type. Let $F, G, H$ be the flags in the diagram below:

[image: here are some flags]

Here, $F$ is a $\sigma$-flag, while $G$ and $H$ are $\sigma'$-flags.

We can define two injections from $[1]$ to $[2]$: $\eta$, which sends $1$ to $1$, and $\zeta$, which sends $1$ to $2$. Both $\sigma|_\eta$ and $\sigma|_\zeta$ are the $1$-vertex type $\sigma'$, but averaging will work differently.

Let's suppose we apply the averaging operator $[\![\cdot ]\!]_{\sigma,\eta}$ to $F$. This gives a multiple of $F|_\eta = G$, because $\eta$ tells us "the vertex labeled $1$ in $\sigma'$ corrresponds to the vertex labeled $1$ in $\sigma$". The normalizing factor $q_{\sigma,\eta}(F)$ is $1$, because no matter which unlabeled vertex of $G$ you label as $2$, you get $F$ back. So $[\![F]\!]_{\sigma,\eta} = G$.

Now apply the averaging operator $[\![\cdot ]\!]_{\sigma,\zeta}$ to $F$. This gives a multiple of $F|_\zeta = H$, because $\zeta$ tells us "the vertex labeled $1$ in $\sigma'$ corresponds to the vertex labeled $2$ in $\sigma$". The normalizing factor $q_{\sigma,\zeta}(F)$ is $\frac12$, because only one of two choices for the other vertex in $H$ will produce $F$. So $[\![F]\!]_{\sigma,\zeta} = \frac12 H$.